# Gtk-Message: 10:59:42.836: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged. PID 16131 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x10

Tags: angular, ubuntu, gtk, electron, yarnpkg

I've cloned an electron project and did a `yarn install`. All the dependencies are now in node_modules. But when I run `yarn run start`. I get this error.

```
Gtk-Message: 10:59:42.836: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
PID 16131 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x10
/home/agile/Desktop/yarnapp/TimeTrackingApp_Electron-master/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x2f27)[0x7f6266e11f27]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f627a81f890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(pthread_mutex_lock+0x0)[0x7f627a816fa0]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XrmQGetResource+0x4a)[0x7f6276e75aaa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6(XGetDefault+0xd6)[0x7f6276e51856]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x9c81e)[0x7f627930f81e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x9f270)[0x7f6279312270]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(cairo_surface_get_font_options+0x80)[0x7f62792e2270]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x2c362)[0x7f627929f362]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(+0x2f464)[0x7f62792a2464]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2(cairo_show_glyphs+0x24)[0x7f6279294344]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0(+0x848b)[0x7f6279a0b48b]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0(+0x86bc)[0x7f6279a0b6bc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(pango_renderer_draw_glyph_item+0x3e)[0x7f62797df20e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(pango_renderer_draw_layout_line+0x471)[0x7f62797dfca1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0(pango_renderer_draw_layout+0x125)[0x7f62797e0075]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0(+0x894a)[0x7f6279a0b94a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_render_layout+0x18d)[0x7f627a1add7d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x219a81)[0x7f627a11fa81]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x16ef2d)[0x7f627a074f2d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x173b83)[0x7f627a079b83]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x216c31)[0x7f627a11cc31]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x382eab)[0x7f627a288eab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_container_propagate_draw+0x1ea)[0x7f627a06feea]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x169fd2)[0x7f627a06ffd2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x11da34)[0x7f627a023a34]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x16ef2d)[0x7f627a074f2d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x173b83)[0x7f627a079b83]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x120341)[0x7f627a026341]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x382eab)[0x7f627a288eab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(gtk_container_propagate_draw+0x1ea)[0x7f627a06feea]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0(+0x169fd2)[0x7f627a06ffd2]
```

The window is opening and closing in like a second. I don't understand what's wrong. I'm trying to run it on Ubuntu OS. Please help. 
Thanks!!

Comment: The first message about dialog mapped without parent is merely a warning, and is not fatal. What happpens after that is the problem (and I don't know what it is, sorry).